# i'm trying to send emails using PHPmailer but i Get this error

Tags: php, windows, xampp, phpmailer

i get this errors

> 2020-06-03 21:08:07 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:25, timeout=300, options=array()
>   2020-06-03 21:08:07 Connection failed.
>
> Error #2: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
>
> OpenSSL Error messages:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number [C:\xampp\htdocs\Go\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 344]
>
> 2020-06-03 21:08:07 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto [C:\xampp\htdocs\Go\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 344]
>
> 2020-06-03 21:08:07 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:25 (Unknown error) [C:\xampp\htdocs\Go\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 344]
>
> 2020-06-03 21:08:07 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
>   SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
>
> Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

```
<?php
require './vendor/autoload.php';


$send = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();

$send->SMTPDebug = 4;// Enable verbose debug output

$send->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$send->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$send->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$send->Username = 'abdelkbirkh2@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$send->Password = 'µµµµµµ';                           // SMTP password
$send->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$send->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$send->setFrom('abdelkbirk@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
$send->addAddress('abdo9@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$send->addAddress('abdok79@gmail.com');               // Name is optional
$send->addReplyTo('abdelk2@gmail.com', 'Information');
$send->addCC('abdelkbir32@gmail.com');
$send->addBCC('abdelkbirk32@gmail.com');

// $send->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
// $send->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$send->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$send->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$send->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$send->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$send->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $send->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: basically your instalation doesn't support the cryptographic functions required. I would follow the troubleshooting guide linked in the error message.

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/1309

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you have a bad combination of encryption mode and port number.

You have set:

```php
$send->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$send->Port = 25;
```

`ssl` mode for `SMTPSecure` is implicit TLS (also known as SMTPS), where the port you connect to will expect you to talk TLS straight away – but you are connecting to a port that is not configured to expect that, so it just won't work.

`ssl` mode will usually be used on port 465, but you can instead switch to STARTTLS mode (explicit TLS), which will work on port 587 for gmail:

```php
$send->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$send->Port = 587;
```

[This exact issue is described in great detail in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#using-encryption) the error message linked you to – the first thing you should **always** do when you have a problem like this is *read the error message!*